# Handling class mismatch in ImageDataGenerator for training and validation sets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How do I work around when my training image dataset have different number of classes than validation set.

Directory structure:

```
- train
  - class1
  - class2
  - class3
- test
  - class1
  - class3
```

```py
idg = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
)
train_gen = idg.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DATA_PATH,
    target_size=(ROWS, COLS),
    batch_size = 32
)

val_gen = idg.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_DATA_PATH,
    target_size=(ROWS, COLS),
    batch_size = 32
)

input_shape = (ROWS, COLS, 3)
nclass = len(train_gen.class_indices)

base_model = applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', 
                                include_top=False, 
                                input_shape=(ROWS, COLS,3))
base_model.trainable = False

model = Sequential()
model .add(base_model)
model .add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model .add(Dropout(0.5))
model .add(Dense(nclass, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(
    train_gen, 
    epochs=20, 
    verbose=True,
    validation_data=val_gen
)
```

The error I get is related to the different number of classes in validation set.

```
Node: 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits'
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,206] labels_size=[32,189]
```

I have 206 classes in the train set and 189 in the validation set. Is it possible to have the same mapping as in train set (the names of the image folders are the same, I'm just missing some of them)

Comment: Quick and dirty workaround is to add empty folder with missing classes

Comment: yes, it was my same suggestion, the better solution is probably using a larger validation set that naturally has all the classes inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

ROWS = 244
COLS = 244

TRAIN_DATA_PATH = "data/train/"
TEST_DATA_PATH = "data/test/"

idg  = ImageDataGenerator()

train_gen = idg.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DATA_PATH,
    target_size=(ROWS, COLS),
    batch_size = 32
)

print(train_gen.class_indices)

val_gen = idg.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_DATA_PATH,
    target_size=(ROWS, COLS),
    batch_size = 32,
    classes = train_gen.class_indices # pass classes name of trainset to val_gen
)

print(val_gen.class_indices)
```

`flow_from_directory` has `classes` option, it can define classes you want.
so you can pass classes of trainset to validset.
`.class_indices` has class_name and it's index.

refer to args of [flow_from_dataframe](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

If the validation set is small and/or some classes are very rare, it may happen that some classes are completely absent from the validation dataset even if they are in the training dataset.

The simplest solution in your case is probably adding empty folders for the missing classes in the validation dataset directory by hand, such that all the classes will be present, even if some will have zero elements.